# how to check user male or female using session in codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter

** in codeigniter How do i check if user logged in is male or female by using session id to compare data from  $this->brid_groom_fetch->get_program_specific_gender() function**

```
public function login_autho() {

        $data = array(
            'uname' => $this->input->post('uname'),
            'upassword' => $this->input->post('upassword')
        );
        $result = $this->login_model->login_user($data);

        print_r($result);
            $data_session_set = array('logged' => TRUE,
            'uname' => $this->input->post('uname'));
        $this->session->set_userdata($data_session_set);
    }
    public function profile() {
        $this->load->view('header');
         $this->load->model('brid_groom_fetch');

         //here how to check gender
         $gender_result=$this->brid_groom_fetch->get_program_specific_gender();

    }
```

in profile controller just i want to check login user is male or femail then

```
     if ($this->session->all_userdata('uname') == "gender") {

          echo 'success';

            }
 else {

            echo 'Fail';
 }
```

Comment: Did you write the function `get_program_specific_gender` ? Is there a database field to identify the gender?

Comment: from this function to get data from database  and i want to compare user name is male then show all female

Comment: here i want to know user gender

Comment: Without knowing the `get_program_specific_gender` function code and your table structures, do you think that it's possible for the stackoverflow users to help you ?